# ratingbar with custom images

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

Is it possible to create a custom rating bar like this? 
  If yes, can you give me an example on how to do it?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you want you custom rating bar to be in your layout?

Comment: in dialog but that doesnt matter imo

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**EDIT**: This is not an appropriate answer, as OP wanted to customize `RatingBar`. But it is still a solution.

It is possible. You just have to put each one of the five image resources in your project and then, make a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/oneStar"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/twoStars"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/threeStars"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fourStars"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fiveStars"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Put your resources as source of your ImageViews. That should be a start for you :D

Comment: i was thinking about that, but i was also hoping that ratingbar could be customized to my needs. thank you anyways.

Comment: This is not the right way. You should use `RatingBar`

Comment: That's just showing 5 images, nothing in common with a RatingBar!

Answer (score 1):

Great tutorial [here](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/).

I will copy important parts in this answer in case the link will be invalid.

First you should create a style which extends the original RatingBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/food_ratingbar_full</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then you need to provide 3 drawables, why? Because you should fill the 3 cases: empty, 50% and full.

This file will be `food_ratingbar_full.xml`

> Here’s an example of a filled rating (cookie):

```
<!-- This is the rating bar drawable that is used to
show a filled cookie. -->
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

</selector>
```

> I just use one image for all states (and it actually looks decent),
>   but as you can see from the selector, there are four different states
>   possible (@drawable/cookie is finally an actuall cookie png image).
>   And the cool thing here is that RatingBar component will automatically
>   fill in part of the cookie when needed based only on “full” and
>   “empty” images (if you support half ratings, as in my example image).

Then to use your style you should just add style attribute in RatingBar XML.

```
style="@style/foodRatingBar
```

The point is: you should create a custom style if you want.

---

Then you could use [`setRotation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29) to rotate it.

> Sets the degrees that the view is rotated around the pivot point. Increasing values result in clockwise rotation.

Comment: i have read this tut but it doesnt let me to use 1/5 system. since its posible only to use 1 or 2 images, 1 for full and second for half. but i need to use 1/5 system, for example 3 out of 5 and so on